# .htaccess redirect from directory to subdomain without changing url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to redirect /blog/ to another project. Without changing the url.
The hole thing almost works with the redirect rules below and using Apache mod_proxy, but only if it hits the index itself on /blog/ it DOES redirect to blog.website.nl.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^website\.nl [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://blog.website.nl/$1 [P,L]
```

When I visit website.nl/blog/category/test/
it works fine!

So why is this still changing the url on /blog/ and how to fix that? 
Thanks! This has been quite a puzzle for me so far.

**Update:**
I managed to get it working. Instead of adding a .htaccess file to blog folder I added this code to the root /htaccess file. Now it all works!

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^website\.nl[NC]
RewriteRule ^/?blog/(.*)$ http://blog.website.nl/$1 [P,L]
```

Comment: You can't do that across domains. Specifying a different host name from the current one always leads to a 301 redirect. Can you explain in more detail what your end goal is?

Comment: You can. With mod_proxy. It works for all other urls so far expect the /blog/ index.

Comment: Ah, I see, overlooked that. Hmm, strange. So when you go to `website.nl/blog` you get a redirect to `blog.website.nl`, or `blog.website.nl/test`? There are no other redirects in place?

Comment: The reason is that the main site is my custom code. But the /blog/ part uses Wordpress.I would like to create the illution that it is all one project.

Comment: /blog/ redirects to blog.website.nl (not wanted)
/blog/article-name does not redirect. And in the background the Wordpress project gets loaded and all is well. (wanted)